# Uninstall git on linux, fedora

Tags: linux, terminal, fedora, git, uninstall

I installed git using

```
sudo yum install git
```

I believe git is corrupted in some manner, when I try to clone a repository from github it asks for my bitbucket password and the clone isn't a clone. I would like to reinstall git, by first uninstalling git. However all the related answers are for ubuntu and windows.

With fedora how do I uninstall git?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
yum reinstall git
```

This will download the package again and uncompress it for installation. However, if that don't fix the issue, I recommend doing the following:

```
yum remove git
yum clean all
yum install git
```

Sometimes, bad copies are cached in the local filesystem and are reused even if reinstalled.